# unable to use a "degree" symbol in xml

Tags: java, xml, symbols

I don't know why but I'm unable to use a "degree" symbol (°) with xml Text. I tried with °
but it doesn't work.
Output is just like this

```
Heart Rate: 78, Respiratory Rate: 102<12, Temp (degF): 70°
, Oxygen Sat (%): 100.Non-invasive Blood Pressure: Systolic: <107, Diastolic: &51 Mean: 70
```

Comment: If this is xml you are really speaking about you should escape that caracter. '°' => &deg; But also '<' becomes &lt; and '&' becomes &amp;

Comment: In what way are you "unable" to use it? It looks fine in the above, for instance.

Answer (score 36):

Use `&#176;` or `&#xb0;` (same as `&#x00b0;`).

This will convert it into degree. See the [unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm) page for details.

Answer (score 8):

Use UTF encoding. Also, there is no `&deg;`-entity in XML.

Answer (score 5):

You may have to use the entity `&#176;` or `&deg;`. You may also have to declare this in the doctype. Here is a pretty good explanation of what to do http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xmlentity.php

Comment: If a fairly straight-forward character like ° isn't working, it suggests a deeper problem with the character encoding. Solving the deeper problem is more appropriate than patching one specific symptom.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a character encoding issue. The degree symbol issue is probably just a symptom of a larger problem.

The binary form of an XML document (e.g., the file / stream / whatever you're reading it from) is encoded using a *character set*. The XML document should [indicate](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charencoding) what character set it's encoded with. This ensures that XML readers can correctly map between the charset of the document and the charset they use.

If the degree symbol isn't working, that suggests that the XML document in question doesn't declare its character set, or declares the wrong one.

Alternately, of course, it could be a problem on *output* and nothing to do with the XML; you haven't said *how* what you're doing isn't working, so we can't say for certain. If it's a problem on output, it's probably a similar problem (e.g., charset issues).

If you haven't already, read [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky, and [the section linked above](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charencoding) of the XML specification. You may also find the Unicode FAQs (particularly [this one](http://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html) and [this one](http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html)) useful.

Answer (score -1):

you have to put Â before °

just copy and paste this Â°

that's weird I know, but this worked for me. I discovered it just looking into a .docx file

Comment: @PaulFloyd In iso-8859-1 (Latin1) the `Â` symbol is encoded in hex as `c2` and the `°` as `b0`. In UTF-8 the `°` is encoded as `c2 b0`. Therefore a doc encoded in Latin1 with `Â°` when interpreted in UTF-8 would appear as `°` (but It's a bit like wearing rose-tinted glasses on while choosing paint).